Pandas: Limiting __repr__ and _repr_html_ behaviour with Xarray
I am storing large xarrays in my dataframe, but any time I display the dataframe in Jupyter or the terminal it takes way to long (11 seconds for a 10 row dataframe). I'd imagine it has something to do with how pandas is grabbing whatever repr information from the individual cells, and it's shoving the whole xarray in there, but then truncates the display after the fact? Who knows?
Is there some pandas setting that will limit this behavior?
Here's the code:



import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr


df = pd.DataFrame({'xarrays':[xr.DataArray(np.random.randn(50,50)) 
                                for  _ in range(10)], # 10 50x50 xarrays
                    'other_stuff':np.arange(10)})


The attached image show the time for displaying the whole frame, the xarray series, and a normal series, but the quick breakdown:



Display Type
Time




Whole df
11 s


Xarray series
6 s


normal series
0 s


directly displaying df repr_html
0.2 s




Expected to display abbreviated/truncated xarray rows without much fuss. Takes way too long just to display.

Can you try df.assign(xarrays=df["xarrays"].map(lambda da: da._repr_html_())).style ?

So it was definitely faster, but produced a weird (yet cool) result. Apparently I can't copy an image into this comment, but it puts the whole repr html for each xarray in each cell, which makes the dataframe huge. Looks neat, but not quite what I'm looking for.
However this does give me an idea. Is there a way to override the pandas formatting/display for a specific datatype? That way I can set that once, and not have to run the assign/map every time.

Not directly to your question here but I'm curious why you've chosen to organize your data in this way? From your screenshot, it seems like you're storing list of Xarray objects in each entry in a Pandas Series. I wonder if there is another way of structuring this data that could help you make better use relationships between these objects.

To be clear, I am storing one xarray in each row of the series. In the dataframe, I've built the column 'xarrays' that is built from a list of xarrays. This translates to a pd.Series of single xarray entries. So to call it a Series of lists of xarrays wouldn't be quite right. To confirm that, running df.xarrays[0] returns a single xarray.
But if your question is hinting at "why store xarrays in the column of a dataframe" here's my reasoning: I have some results that are best stored as xarrays (of varying shapes) and I want to filter them and manipulate them based on meta data in the columns

Solved it! Apparently the option I was looking for was pandas' display.pprint_nest_depth. After limiting that to 1, things sped up considerably, but I'm not yet sure the implication of that.
# ------- Same dataframe as before ----------------

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr


df = pd.DataFrame({'xarrays':[xr.DataArray(np.random.randn(50,50)) 
                                for  _ in range(10)], # 10 50x50 xarrays
                    'other_stuff':np.arange(10)})

# ------- Experimenting with pprint settings ----------------

import IPython.display

# NOTE apparently my computer has sped up a bit, so the default display speed has sped up from 11 seconds to 5 seconds
# but that is still way to slow

pd.set_option('display.pprint_nest_depth',3) # (default)

IPython.display.display(df) # 5.4 seconds 
IPython.display.display(df.xarrays) # 2.7 seconds (default)

pd.set_option('display.pprint_nest_depth',2) 
IPython.display.display(df)# also 5.4 seconds
IPython.display.display(df.xarrays)# also 2.7 seconds

pd.set_option('display.pprint_nest_depth',1) 

# SUCCESS!
IPython.display.display(df)# 0.2 seconds
IPython.display.display(df.xarrays)# 0.1 seconds

